# Delphi - Load file into string Grid

Tags: delphi

I am trying to load a simple timetable (urnik.txt) into my string grid.First I check if the
file exists, if not then I create it, otherwise load it.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j, k: Integer;
  Seznam: TStrings;
  ApplicationPath: string;
const
  dan = '  PoToSrČePe';
begin
  ApplicationPath := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
  if not FileExists(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt') then
  begin
    Seznam := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
        AdvStringGrid1.Cells[i, 0] := Copy(dan, 2 * i + 1, 2);
      for i := 1 to AdvStringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
        AdvStringGrid1.Cells[0, i] := IntToStr(i) + '.ura';
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
        Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid1.Cols[i]);
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
        Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid1.rows[j]);
      Seznam.SaveToFile(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt');
    finally
      Seznam.free;
    end;
  end
  else
    Seznam := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Seznam.LoadFromFile(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt');
    k := 0;
    for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
      for j := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
      begin
        AdvStringGrid1.Cells[i, j] := Seznam.Strings[k];
        Inc(k);
      end;
  finally
    Seznam.free;
  end;
end;
```

To save the contents of the string grid I use :

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Seznam: TStrings;
  ApplicationPath: string;
begin
  ApplicationPath := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
  Seznam := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
      Seznam.AddStrings(AdvStringGrid1.Cols[i]);
    Seznam.SaveToFile(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt');
  finally
    Seznam.free;
  end;
end;
```

However, if the file does not exist, I get an error :
[image: error]

What am I doing wrong ??

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
I,j,k:Integer;
ApplicationPath: string;
Seznam:TStrings;
Const dan = '  PoToSrČePe';
begin
  ApplicationPath := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
  if not FileExists(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt') then
  begin
    Seznam := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
        AdvStringGrid1.Cells[i, 0] := Copy(dan, 2 * i + 1, 2);
      for i := 1 to AdvStringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
        AdvStringGrid1.Cells[0, i] := IntToStr(i) + '.ura';
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
        Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid1.Cols[i]);
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
        Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid1.rows[j]);
      Seznam.SaveToFile(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt');
    finally
      Seznam.free;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Seznam := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Seznam.LoadFromFile(ApplicationPath + '\Urnik.txt');
      k := 0;
      for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
        for j := 0 to AdvStringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
        begin
          AdvStringGrid1.Cells[i, j] := Seznam.Strings[k];
          Inc(k);
        end;
    finally
      Seznam.free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This kind of works.... I hope it's OK.....

Comment: Seznam is freed twice in Form.Create if file does not exist. This is the reason for the error. Uwe is probably right in the assumption that a begin/end clause is missing.

Comment: Why don't you indent your code so that it is legible and intelligible?

Comment: I also removed all the specific delphi version tags. They are meant to indicate which version of the compiler you are using, and can be useful in case the problem depends on differences between different versions. Don't just spew out random versions for the sake of it. The tags are meant to convey information. Don't fill them with random noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing begin/end for the else clause in FormCreate.

To be more specific: When the file does not exist, you create and free Seznam. As the else doesn't have a begin/end only the Seznam := TStringList.Create; is skipped, the rest of the code is executed even if the file doesn't exist.

In that case you access Seznam in the try-finally block, which might work or not, as Seznam is already freed in the if-then part. Latest when you get to the second SezNam.Free, you are going to free an already freed instance which most likely is the cause of the error.

Comment: Not sure that i understand you...?